# How to detect formatted input errors from standard input?

Tags: c++, error-handling

When trying to input something such as:

```
Please enter the number of elements: 4

Enter the list to be sorted: 4 x3 1 6
```

I get an output of:

```
The sorted list is:error: invalid input
```

How can I make it so that if there is an error is solely executes the error invalid input statement, and visa versa?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[50], n, i, j, temp;
    cout << "Please enter the number of elements:";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the list to be sorted:"; 
    cout << endl;
    if (cin >> n) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cin >> a[i];

        for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < (n - i); ++j)
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
        }
        cout << "The sorted list is:";
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cout << " " << a[i];
    }
    else (!(cin >> n));
    {
        cout << "error: invalid input" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is (probably) the error: `else (!(cin >> n));` There is no condition after `else`. The compiler reads this very different than it's (probably) meant: `(!(cin >> n));` becomes the `else`-body. The block afterwards is just a block which is always executed. (It's not the `else` block.)

Comment: Btw. there is another flaw: In line 9: `cin >> n;`, then in line 13 again: `if (cin  >> n)`. So, you read `n` twice. Is this intended? (And, if so, why?)

Comment: You should debug your code to see why you get this output. This way you will find your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading `n` twice from `cin`. In your `if` test for `cin` you should just check `cin`, i.e.,

```
`if (cin)`
```

The second problem is with your else block

```
else (!(cin >> n));
{
    cout << "error: invalid input" << endl;
}
```

Despite the formatting what this does is

```
else
{
    // 'n' read from cin, return value negated and discarded
    (!(cin >> n))
}
// always executed
cout << "error: invalid input" << endl;
```

I guess that the `cin` should have been in a comment

```
else // (!(cin >> n));
{
    cout << "error: invalid input" << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is correct but it doesn't answer the question. In the question the input is wrong. So it is correct that "error: invalid input" is printed. The question is, why "The sorted list is:" is also printed

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for error checking.

1) Ask the user to input the numbers after getting the size.
2) Begin by storing these numbers as chars, use the function isdigit() to check if the user is inputting correctly.

```
while (A[i].isdigit() == false) // if it is not a number
cout<<"Enter again : "
```

3) Convert these characters and store them in an array, if the number inputted is correct.

Hope this helps.